# I have added Splash screen plugin but splash screen not working in cordova visual studio 2015

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015, cordova-plugins

I added this in config.xml file. is it any Remaining to add?

```
`<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />

<platform name="android">
    <splash src="res/screens/android/320X470.jpg" density="land-hdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/320X470.jpg" density="land-ldpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/320X470.jpg" density="land-mdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/320X470.jpg" density="land-xhdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/320X470.jpg" density="port-hdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/320X470.jpg" density="port-ldpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/320X470.jpg" density="port-mdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/320X470.jpg" density="port-xhdpi" />
  </platform>

 <vs:plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" version="3.0.0" />`
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case the splash screen was not displayed long enough (although "SplashScreenDelay" was set). The reason for that was the following line in the app.Ready event:

```
navigator.splashscreen.hide();
```

I removed that line and the splash screen worked as expected.